# Error in Comparing the same column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching the values from the column as the value of integer and doing this for two user so i tried to get the value from the table and compare it but unfortunately for both greater and smaller comparsion i am getting the same result nothing changed.

How do i compare the column values?

My code is like below-----

```
$sqlres="select membership from register where mid='".$_SESSION['mid']."' ";
$pres=mysql_query($sqlres); 
$prest=mysql_fetch_array($pres);
$sqlres1="select membership from register where matri_id='".$row['mtr_id']."' ";
$pres1=mysql_query($sqlres);    
$prest1=mysql_fetch_array($pres);


if($pres<$pres1)
{
//somethiung   enter code here
}
```

Comment: As stated in [the introduction to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php): *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Comment: Where is `$row` defined?  Perhaps you want to read about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)?

Comment: @eggyal yes i had `$row` for the search show display the resistered user on search

Comment: @muistooshort tabel is like in one tabel there is colum membership from where fiirst the login user value is nobtained and then for other user who get searched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't use mysql_* it is deprecated, use mysqli_* or PDO instead.

As for your question, `mysql_fetch_array` as the name suggests, returns an array, not a single value, so you need to get the first value in the array:

```
if($pres[0]<$pres1[0])
{
//somethiung   enter code here
}
```

Comment: They are not deprecated. Their use is discouraged. And this is because some developers can't escape their queries propery :) http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

You save the result in $prest and $prest1 (with "t"), not in $pres and $pres1. I suggest always using the variable $query for the query string and $result for the result table. Only when you fetch the result should you use a custom variable name to not get confused.

You can use something like

```
if($prest['membership']<$prest1['membership']){//do stuff here}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the piece of code that you provided, you are comparing the resources that mysql_query returned not the values of the columns. You have to do this:

```
if( $prest['membership'] < $prest1['membership'] ){
  //Some stuff going here
}
```

**Advice:** Name your variables properly. Use more describing names. After 2 months you won't remember the difference between `$prest` and `$prest1`